# Reach django user from javascript template

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views

I'm following Corey Shafer's django guide and I have run into some problems he doesn't cover. I'm trying to make profiles that are visible to everyone but only editable by the user itself. In my views.py I have a boolean "editable", and this part is working. However, I can't get that boolean to my js file... Code below.

```
const button = document.getElementById("button");


button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const form = document.getElementById("form");
    var bool = {{ user.profile.editable }};

    if(form.style.display == "none" && bool){
        form.style.display = "block";
    }else{
        form.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

When I inspect it in the browser it gives me a syntaxError because I'm using '{'.
And here is the code from my views.py:

```
@login_required
def profile(request, username):

    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    editable = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f"Profile successfully updated!")
            return redirect("profile")
    else:
        user_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        "user_form": user_form,
        "profile_form": profile_form
    }

    if request.user == user:
        editable = True

    return render(request, "users/profile.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you want to access the editable variable, you just need to pass it into your context:

```py
context['editable'] = editable
```

Secondly, it's considered bad practice to pass Django variables directly into JS `<script>` tags. If you want to access this data then either create a hidden input with the value or use the `json_script` tag:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script

Thirdly, it seems your code just renders and processes a profile form. I would suggest putting the editable check at the start of the view and redirecting if the user is not accessing their own profile.

Comment: The json_script tag worked like a charm! Only problem I have is that the profile site will still display the logged in user's info, instead of the user on the url. I seem to be able to fix that by adding all the info into the "context" and then rendering that, and just referring to the "context" in my template instead of "user.profile.username" for instance. Would that be the "correct" way to solve the problem? And thanks for the help!

Comment: Just chance instance=request.user on your form to instance=user - user being the one called by username in the URL

Answer (score 0):

get the value as a str and check like this: `"{{ user.profile.editable }}"==="True"`

```
const button = document.getElementById("button");


button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const form = document.getElementById("form");
    var bool = "{{ user.profile.editable }}"==="True";

    if(form.style.display == "none" && bool){
        form.style.display = "block";
    }else{
        form.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```